# Unable to post data through code but working with swagger

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am calling following line to post data which is not inserting data, but works with loopback or swagger

> this.http.post(this.Root_url2 + 'busbookings', excelBody)

Complete code as below:

```
    import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    @Injectable()
    export class LoadexcelService {
    private Root_url2 = "http://localhost:3000/api/";
      constructor( private http: HttpClient) {
       }    

        postRouteList(routeExcel) {
            routeExcel.forEach((route) => {

            var excelBody = {
                "routeid":route.routeid,
                "from":route.from,
                "to":route.to,
                "price":route.price,
                "departuredate":route.departuredate,
                "departuretime":route.departuretime,
                "arrivaldate":route.arrivaldate,
                "busType":route.busType          
            }
            this.http.post(this.Root_url2 + 'busbookings', excelBody)    
       }); 
         }
    }
```

I dont have any issues in posting data through swagger through this link

http://localhost:3000/api/

[image: Swagger/loopback works]

Comment: It won't work unless you `subscribe` to the observables

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error...

Comment: no error..i will add suscribe

Comment: its working with subscribe ..thanks :) please add as answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable`s are never fired until you subscribe, so you will need to call `subscribe` on each one

```
this.http.post(this.Root_url2 + 'busbookings', excelBody)
         .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```